# I am wanting to use importXML in Google Sheets to pull in just the Total Price

Tags: xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am having difficulty with my importXML function. I am trying to pull the data in from a webpage with just the Total value shown. Currently the importXML function =IMPORTXML("website.com","//span[@class='woocommerce-Price-amount amount']") pulls in every price value for each product as well as sub-total VAT etc and Total. I was hoping i could filter this so that the cell just returns the "Total" value. Inspecting the Total element, I can see there is the following element

scope="row">
Total:

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Can you please provide the real website link and a working copy of your sheet?

Comment: Hi, It's impossible to answer while we don't know the selector for this 'scope' element and it's relation to this import. Please provide a real website name so we can check

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your input on this and apologies for wasting your time. I have figured out what i was doing wrong though. I was unable to share the url as it contains customer data. However, when using the following =index(IMPORTXML(website.com,"//span[@class='woocommerce-Price-amount amount']"),2) by indexing and adding the "2" it defined what i needed. If i selected 3 it showed the individiual item price and so on. Apologies again and thank you for your help